# shell_exec chmod on crontab doesn't work?

Tags: php, cron

I have a line in crontab and php script like below:

**/etc/crontab: -**

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/xxx.php
```

**php: -**

```
<?php

shell_exec("sudo chmod 655 /files/to/path/xxx.wac");

?>
```

When I run manually

> sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/xxx.php

It works as what it should be. However when crontab reach one minute lapse, it doesn't execute the command in php as it should. 
**Note: Checked on syslog it does run that command after every minutes.**

Comment: What are the permissions on xxx.php and xxx.wac?

Comment: why would you ever do this as a cron job?

Comment: Hi @kojow7, the permission on xxx.php is 777 root:root and xxx.wac 600 ec2user:ec2user

Comment: @Dagon, what are others option to do besides? The infrastructure is remote server files being rsync into the cloud server folder.

Comment: Would ACLs work here?

Comment: What about using the -p (or maybe better the -a) flag to use with rsync?

Comment: @kojow7 yes, after changing the acl it works. It might not be the option to change or modify over on the remote server, lets just assume to have it done over on the cloud level only.

Comment: @kojow7 changing ACL manually it works but not in crontab.

Comment: @kojow7 notice my folder has a trailing plus "+" could that be the problem?

Comment: @EricT, no the + sign means you are using ACLs. If you use ACLs to force the permissions, you shouldn't need to use crontab.

Comment: Was this problem solved? I'll appreciate any tip